# Solr function highlight for java web app

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, solr, solrj

I have search the net, but cannot seems to find the solutions on how to do Solr highlight function. I am using java eclipse jsp & servlets.

**F.Y.I** I am using Solr 5

My objective is when user search the words "**Hello**" The word hello will be **highlighted**.

For example: **Hello** I suck at programming!

Any expert in Solr can give me some solution? I am sure that people will down vote my question. But I got to give it a try.

Here is the my code that I have tried. I had commented SOLR highlight in the following code how any expert in Solr can take it a look and tell me what I should do next. Also wish that some expert in Solr can share their source code if they done something like this before.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException,
                MalformedURLException {

            System.out.println("request parameter: "
                    + request.getParameter("search"));
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            try {
                HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/name/");
                SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
                String test;
                String content;

                //SOLR HIGHLIGHT
                query.set("hl", "true");
                query.set("hl.snippets", "1");
                query.set("hl.simple.pre", "<em>");
                query.set("hl.requireFieldMatch","true");
                query.set("q", "value:supreme");
                query.set("hl.fl", "id,content");



                query.setQuery(request.getParameter("search"));


                query.setFields("id");
                query.setStart(0);

                QueryResponse response1 = solr.query(query);
                SolrDocumentList results = response1.getResults();
                for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
                    test = results.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the snippet you have provided you are searching on field supreme but wish to highlight fields id and content. As far as I know, highlighting allows you to highlight the field on which match was found.
Try highlighting supreme and check the results.

Also highlighting results can be had from calling getHighlighting()
`QueryResponse response1 = solr.query(query); 
response1.getHighlighting()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if I want to highlight the words that the user search? What should I put?

Comment: And also as I printed the result in a JSP page, do I need to add some code in my jsp? @Gautam thank you.

Comment: First you need to know what field/fields is the user searching on. The query will form accordingly. Since the user is searching for some text in certain field/fields, highlight same fields. Say we have fields called item and category and user wants to search for value Apple which we want to match on item or category, you can apply highlighting on item and category. When SOLR returns the results, you can use getResults() to get the matching documents and getHighlighting() to know which field was the document matched on. Rest how you render it on UI will be as per your design.

Comment: Okay thank you so much! Anyway just a question. If I want to display multiple results with the same keyword is it possible to use ArrayList to do it? Basically is when user search the word "google" then all the results from Solr with the word google will be display. Something like google search. @Gautam

Comment: Short answer, yes you can show all results matching the user search. You will need to provide some more details on what you want to do here. It all depends on your use case. Like if you want to show recommendations as google does, below text box, you sure can. You might want to reduce the size of payload by using "fl" query to give you only select few fields on which you want to search instead of loading entire documents.

Comment: Hello, I need to edit my Solrconfig.xml file in order for the Solr hl function to work right? @Gautam

Answer (score 0):

You're searching in the field `value`, but you're only asking for highlighting to be performed on the fields `id` and `content`.

```
query.set("hl.requireFieldMatch","true");
query.set("q", "value:supreme");
query.set("hl.fl", "id,content");
```

Since you're also telling Solr to *only* highlight in fields where there's a match, no highlighting will take place. You'll have to either include the field you're expecting the match in (`value`) in your `hl.fl` list, or you'll might have to drop the `hl.requireFieldMatch` setting (possibly depending on the analysis chain and how the fields are indexed).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want to highlight the words that the user search? What should I do in order to make it happen.

Comment: And also I printed the result in a JSP page, do I need to add some code in my jsp? Thank you! @MatsLindh.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Actaully I want to highlight the words that the user search? What should I do in order to make it happen? @MatsLindh

Comment: Yes. Those will be included in the response. @Gautam included an example, and you can use the debugger or API Documentation for SolrJ to see the data methods available to you. You'll have to display those in your templates to present them to the user. How you do that will be up to yourself (usually assigning it to the view, and then reference it your templating language)

Comment: Hello, I need to edit my Solrconfig.xml in order for the hl work right?   @MatsLindh

Answer (score 0):

Use this for highlighting:

```
String searchTerm="harry",result=results.toString();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(" + 
Pattern.quote(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) + ")",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);

        result = pattern.matcher(result.toString()).replaceAll("<strong>$1</strong>");
        results=results.add(result);
        System.out.println(result);*/
```